# Connection String Name don't display in SqlDataSource dropdown list

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ssms

I configure Connection String in web.config file with named "DBCS"

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBCS" connectionString="data source=.\MSSQL; database=LCDDemo; Initial Catalog=LCDDemo; integrated security=SSPI"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

but when I try to access it from sqlDataSource then "DBCS" does't display on dropdownList. 
I also mention it in below image.[image]

Answer (score 2):

the string is missing an important element:

```
<add name="DBCS" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="data source=.\MSSQL; database=LCDDemo; 
     Initial Catalog=LCDDemo; integrated security=SSPI" />
```

i have no documentation to back my answer and explain this behaviour but you can test it in seconds adding the missing  `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` to your configuration.